# Questions about effects setups on specific songs?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if it were ok to post questions pertaining to effects used on songs? Like:

> "What bass effects are being used in this song?"

Or

> "How to replicate the **XX** sound in this song?"

Comment: These questions are usually too localized.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you.

Comment: Any place that they can be asked? @AmericanLuke